# Python ctypes how does one skip optional arguments

Tags: python, c, wrapper, ctypes

I have a function in the header im wrapping

```
IMPORT_FUNCTION int WINAPI GetStuff(int id, StuffStruct* stuff, StuffList *stuffList=NULL);
```

Im wrapping this function with

```
mydll.GetStuff.argtypes = [c_int, POINTER(StuffStruct), POINTER(StuffList)]
```

Also tried skipping

```
mydll.GetStuff.argtypes = [c_int, POINTER(StuffStruct)]
```

I need to call this function without specifying last parameter. I tried None and creating a null pointer like this  POINTER(StuffList)()
I feel like i should user prototype but i don't know at this point.

```
stuff = StuffStruct()
np = POINTER(StuffList)()
mydll.GetStuff(2, byref(stuff), None) # tried this 
mydll.GetStuff(2, byref(stuff), np) # tried this 
mydll.GetStuff(2, byref(stuff)) # tried this
```

Comment: How about mydll.GetStuff(2, byref(stuff), byref(None))

Comment: That prototype looks like C++ to me. C doesn't support optional arguments with default values. In C you can have a pointer argument that's ignored if `NULL`, in which case pass it as `None` via ctypes. But if this is really a C++ library without a well-defined C API, then you'll be better off using cython or CFFI.

Comment: @eryksun you are right it is C++ lib, but with well defined C API i guess except for this moment. This default values work fine with integers since i can pass 0 fine. But NULL pointer is not.

Answer (score 1):

`None` is the equivalent of NULL in Python.  Declare `argtypes` for all three parameters.  The following is correct:

```
mydll.GetStuff.argtypes = [c_int, POINTER(StuffStruct), POINTER(StuffList)]    

stuff = StuffStruct()
mydll.GetStuff(2, byref(stuff), None)
```

`ctypes` doesn't know about optional arguments so you have to pass something. You could always wrap the ctypes call in a Python function and then call it:

```
def GetStuff(id,stuff,stuffList=None):
    mydll.GetStuff(id,stuff,stuffList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mydll.GetStuff(2, byref(stuff), byref(0))
```

and

```
mydll.GetStuff(2, byref(stuff), byref(None))
```

or

```
np = POINTER([])
```